# ¿Como Puedo convertir la fecha correctamente? sin que me salga este mensaje

Tags: c#, asp.net

> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputGenericControl' al tipo
>   'System.IConvertible'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CapaEntidades;
using CapaLogicaNegocio;

namespace CapaPresentacion
{
    public partial class NuevaSeccionEnterate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Registro Del Nuevo Foro Enterate

                Enterate objEnterate = GetEntity();

                //Enviar A CapaLogicNegocio

            }
        }

        public Enterate GetEntity()

        {
            Enterate objEnterate = new Enterate();
            objEnterate.Id_ent = 0;
            objEnterate.titu_ent = nuevotitulo.InnerText;
            objEnterate.cod_img_ent = imagensection.InnerText;
            objEnterate.parf_ent = nuevoparrafo.InnerText;
            objEnterate.fech_art_ent = Convert.ToDateTime(fechapublicacion);
            return objEnterate;
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mas alla del error que te dice cual es el problema, cual seria la pregunta?

Comment: Que tipo de control es `fechapublicacion`?

Comment: ¿No será que debes acceder al .text (innerText, whatever..) de fechapublicacion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes especificar que tipo de es fechapublicacion, o intenta:

DateTime.ParseExact(fechapublicacion.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)